# Springboot saves date to database 1 day off

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jvm

### Problem

I am writing an application with SpringBoot using hibernate writing data to MySQL database. I get data for the entity from HTML form using thymeleaf.
When I am saving records to a database they are 1 day behind so 2019-04-09 becomes 2019-04-08.

### What worked so far

The only solution to fix this that I found so far was to change the time of my system to be in UTC but obviously this is going to work differently for whoever I am writing the application for. I've seen many topics on this around the internet but most of the time it is fixed using JVM hacks and I would like to do it in a proper way if possible.

### What baffles me

I am using java.time.LocalDate which supposedly doesn't use time-zone and it saves this date to SQL database column with type 'Date'. I tried changing my database time zone to UTC but that doesn't seem to make a difference. The only thing that makes a difference is changing my windows time to UTC.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/boxbaza?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=box
spring.datasource.password=box
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

**Hibernate entity**

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "dataUmowy")
private LocalDate dataUmowy;
```

**Controller**

```
@SessionAttributes("ofwca")
@Controller
public class OfwcaController {

@Autowired
private OfwcaDao ofwcaDao;

@RequestMapping(value = "/panelOfwca/daneOfwca", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String daneOfwca(Model model, @ModelAttribute("ofwca") Ofwca ofwca){

    ofwcaDao.save(ofwca);

    model.addAttribute("title", "Dane " + ofwca.getImie() + " " + ofwca.getNazwisko());
    model.addAttribute("ofwca", ofwca);
    return "panelOfwca/daneOfwca";
}
```

**Data access object**

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface OfwcaDao extends CrudRepository<Ofwca, Integer> {

public List<Ofwca> findAll();

public Ofwca findByIdOfwca(Integer idOfwca);

}
```

**html form**

```
<form role="form" method="post" th:action="@{/panelOfwca/daneOfwca}" th:object="${ofwca}">

  <div class="form-group col-xs-4">
    <label for="dataUmowy">Data umowy</label>
    <input type="date" id="dataUmowy" th:field="*{dataUmowy}" class="form-control">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is the column type in the database?

Comment: in MySQL the type is 'DATE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I haven't used Hibernate (and java.time within it in particular) for a very long time, your issue very much looks related to the fact that your MySQL server expects "dates" with UTC timezone and your local server is running in `Europe/Berlin` timezone which is (at least) UTC+1.
That means, any date, e.g. 2019-08-04 is, I guess, saved as one day before (e.g. 2019-07-04) - this is because of 1-2 hour difference between the timezones.

In most cases, it's best to treat all date/time values without timezone as having UTC timezone by default.
If that's not possible, then you should tune your DB settings to use the same timezone as your Java app.

Further readings:

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11396
- https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,667136,667159#msg-667159
- https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/issues/1446
- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93444

Answer (score 3):

This problem occurs with your jdbc URL:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/boxbaza?serverTimezone=UTC
```

You have to change the jdbc connection URL as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/boxbaza?serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin
```

I have fixed my problem of 1 day behind,with above replacement.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem for now by using a different timezone for hibernate (which my local server is in) but I am not sure how it is going to work in the future when I deploy the app to the cloud. Might have to change the parameters based on the web server again.

```
serverTimezone=Europe/Berlin
```